# Alamofire strange JSON prefix - Swift 2.0

Tags: json, swift, prefix, swift2, alamofire

Im trying to get a JSON file from an API, but Alamofire (branch: Swift 2.0) returns the file with a strange prefix (Alamofire.Result.Success). I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but im new to alamofire. How can I just get a NORMAL file that I can use with SwiftyJSON.

My code:

```
func getText (image: UIImage){

    let url = "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1"
    let apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
    let mode = "document_photo"
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        url,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
                data: apiKey.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                name: "apikey"
            )
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
                data: mode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                name: "mode"
            )
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "file",fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON  { _, _, json in

                        print(JSON)

                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Output from print(JSON):

```
Alamofire.Result<Swift.AnyObject>.Success([text_block: (
        {
        height = 127;
        left = 0;
        text = "\U2022 response()\n\U2022 responseString(encoding: NSStringEncoding)\n\U2022 responseJSON(options: NSJS0NReading0ptions)\n\U2022 responsePropertyList(options: NSPropertyListRead0ptions)";
        top = 0;
        width = 487;
    }
)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the closure argument for your call to `upload.responseJSON(_:completionHandler:)`, the parameter you've given the name `json` is being passed as an Alamofire `Result` Enumeration (see [source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/swift-2.0/Source/Result.swift)).

You should be able to get at the associated data for that enum by accessing its `value` property, like so:

```
upload.responseJSON  { _, _, json in
  print(json.value!)
}
```

Additionally, check out [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) when you get a chance (a popular library for handling JSON in Swift).

Comment: Thx. But now, if I do  `case .Success(let upload, _, _): upload.responseJSON { _, _, _json in let json = JSON(_json.data!) if let ocr_results = json["text_block"][0]["text"].string {  }  }` I'll get an error at `let json = JSON(_json.data!)` because _json.data is nil

Comment: @NMAC427 you want `_json.value!` if you are going for the serialized response from the `Result.Success` associated data